# RoR in_time_zone issue with daylight savings time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone, timezone-offset

I am running on Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.12. When I run the following code with a object_time in timezone EDT (-4):

```
object_time.in_time_zone(ActiveSupport::TimeZone[-4])
```

I get the same value as that of the object_time which is great. However, when i run:

```
object_time.in_time_zone(ActiveSupport::TimeZone[-3])
```

I get the same value as the line of code above this one.

Anyone have any idea what might be going on?

Answer (score 0):

```
(object_time.in_time_zone(ActiveSupport::TimeZone[0]) + timezone_offset.hours)
```

will you give any DateTime object in which ever timzone offset you would like...enjoy.